# How do you configure visual studio 2012 to use a different editor for editing script tasks is integration services (SSIS)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ssis, text-editor, script-task

Is it possible to configure visual studio 2012 to use a different editor for editing script tasks is integration services (SSIS)? If so how?

I have looked in **Tools** > **Options** > **Business Intelligence designers** > **Integration Services Designers** - which looks the logical place for this, but cannot see any options.

My reason for changing it it takes SOOOO long for a new instance of VS2012 to spin up when I just want to check or make a minor alteration to the script task.

Thanks.